# Advantages of using algorithms for uninitialised memory

Tags: c++, stl

The `<memory>` header of the stl provides algorithms for uninitialised memory, namely:

```
uninitialized_copy()
uninitialized_copy_n()
uninitialized_fill()
uninitialized_fill_n()
[....]
```

Is there any advantage in using them over their respective counterparts from `<algorithm>`?

Comment: That they work for *uninitialized* memory.

Comment: @BoPersson - That was going to be my guess.

Comment: Exception safety, if an exception is thrown all contructed object are destroyed, and other goodies to circumvent miss conceived classes and iterators.

Comment: sometimes when you copy you need to call copy constructor, and sometime you can't call copy constructor if object wasn't initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use these when you don’t want to first *default-construct* the elements of your range (because they can’t be so constructed or for performance).

Comment: Does std::copy first default construct an element to overwrite it after?

Comment: @OutOfBound: It doesn’t, but it requires that there already be destination objects constructed _somehow_.  For types that can go uninitialized, this is a conceptual operation that costs nothing at runtime, but even then `vector` and `string` zero-initialize.